# proper user and group configuration for eclipse android jenkins

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, android, eclipse, jenkins

On **ubuntu 10.0.4**
Did **sudo su**
Then installed eclipse in **/root/eclipse** (only wget and unzip, no apt-get)
Then installed android sdk in **/root/android-sdk-linux_x86** (only wget and unzip, no apt-get)
Run with **gksudo /root/eclipse/eclipse &**
No issues. Development working fine.

Then installed jenkins in **/var/lib/jenkins** (using apt-get)

**Issue:**
Now when I use jenkins "Execute shell" option and call shell scripts,
I get permissions issues like for example:
/root/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/android: **Permission denied**
**Cannot find** /root/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/pre_setup.xml

**How do I configure users and groups in this kind of scenario,

so that I can run scripts from jenkins (running as the jenkins user) ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install everything into jenkins's home directory instead of root.